# Bluetooth headphones streaming issue

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I've just bought some Bluetooth headphones, the Bluedio T3. These work great when I first connect. If I disconnect and reconnect, either via the Mac or by power cycling the headphones, there is bad interference in the audio – it skips a lot. If I turn bluetooth off and on again on the Mac and reconnect, it works fine again. The headphones also work fine on my iPhone after disconnecting and connecting, so this is limited to Mac. Any ideas?

Comment: This could be a driver issue or just a broken airport network card. Have you tried connecting a different bluetooth device to your mac. Maybe try connecting your phone to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was the headphones. I bought another pair which work great after power cycle – the August EP650B. Much better sound quality and comfier too.